# I keep getting an "Expected brace" & "Unexpected token" error

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

So I'm building a website in Wordpress and I want the header to be full screen but I'm getting problems with responsiveness so I wanted to make it so the code I use only applies to desktop PC's and Tablets; however I keep getting these expected brace & unexpected token errors. Does anybody know how to solve this? Maybe there is a better way to fix my issue, if so please let me know.. This is the code I'm talking about:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:768px){ 
  min-height: 100vh; 
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to select an element to style and you haven't done that.

Something like

```
@media only screen and (min-width:768px){ 
 header {
     min-height: 100vh; 
     display: flex; 
     flex-direction: column;
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm editing in Divi wordpress theme and I'm placing this ccs in a specific section which targets the element i'm styling. However when pressing help it says: "css added here targets the following class: .et_pb_section_o". I tried @media only screen and (min-width:768px){ 
  .et_pb_section_0 {
     min-height: 100vh; 
     display: flex; 
     flex-direction: column;
   }
}